# Ansible playbook on ubuntu 20

Tags: server, software-installation, scripts, automation, ansible

How to write Ansible Playbook to install different applications on different hosts on Ubuntu 20.04
Conditions

1. When running a playbook it should ask for the host name (we must give the specific host name)

For all the packages we have to give numbers like 1,2,3, .....

After giving the host name it should ask for the package number, at that time we should give that number, the specific package should be installed on the specific host

Answer (score 0):

I would organize my Ansible repo to have separate role for each software and then use `ansible_hostname` fact of `gather_facts` module as condition to install software for the specific host. I would go with a folder structure like this:

```
└── ansible_repo
    ├── roles
    │   ├── vim
    │   │   └── tasks
    │   │       └── main.yml
    │   ├── tmux
    │   │   └── tasks
    │   │       └── main.yml
    │   └── vlc
    │       └── tasks
    │           └── main.yml
    ├── inventory
    └── playbook.yml
```

The contents of the `playbook.yml` will go along something like this:

```
# playbook.yml
- hosts: all
  become: true
# run roles
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - vim
    - tmux
    - vlc
```

The `main.yml` inside each task will follow this template (there vim is used):

```
---
# tasks file for vim

- name: Install vim
  apt:
    name:
      - vim
    when gather_facts.ansible_hostname = "host1" or "host3"
```

You can store the host name in `inventory` file as well.

While this one would work, but it would not be the best practice, I think. A better way would be to group your hosts based on what packages the need and then use the specific roles for that group.